# Refacto tips for a JS event on hover

Tags: javascript, text, hover

I would like some tips about an simple hover that change the content of a description above the list.
I was trying to do it using before, after and hover pseudo classes but I couldn't make it right so I switch to Js and managed to do this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="description">This is an awesome content</div>

<div id="list"> 
  <span id="workfield_1" onMouseOver="changeparagraph()" onMouseOut="originalparagraph()"> Workfield_1 </span> | 
  <span id="workfield_2" onMouseOver="changeparagraph()" onMouseOut="originalparagraph()"> Workfield_2 </span> | 
  <span id="workfield_3" onMouseOver="changeparagraph()" onMouseOut="originalparagraph()"> Workfield_3 </span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
const description = document.getElementById("description")

function changeparagraph() {
  switch (event.target.id) {
    case 'workfield_1': 
      description.innerHTML="A nice content about workfield_1";
      break;
    case 'workfield_2': 
      description.innerHTML="A nice content about workfield_2";
      break;
    case 'workfield_3': 
      description.innerHTML="A nice content about workfield_3";
      break;
    }
  } 

  function originalparagraph() {
    description.innerHTML="This is an awesome content";
  }
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to do it in a proper, less repetitive way, or in a different way ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Use CSS with `:hover` to hide or show elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's better like this :

```
<div id="description">This is an awesome content</div>

<div id="list"> 
  <span onMouseOver="changeparagraph('A nice content about workfield_1')" onMouseOut="originalparagraph()"> Workfield_1 </span> | 
  <span onMouseOver="changeparagraph('A nice content about workfield_2')" onMouseOut="originalparagraph()"> Workfield_2 </span> | 
  <span onMouseOver="changeparagraph('A nice content about workfield_3')" onMouseOut="originalparagraph()"> Workfield_3 </span>
</div>
```

js :

```
const description = document.getElementById("description")

function changeparagraph(msg) {
      description.innerHTML=msg;
  } 

  function originalparagraph() {
    description.innerHTML="This is an awesome content";
  }
```

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/b80jzte3/